# Firebase profiler for firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Does the Firebase CLI command `firebase database: profile --project <project_id>` does not work for Firestore? Cause it's stuck at 0 operations for me, does it only work for Real-Time database?. If so, is there another way to profile Firestore operations?. Sorry, it only works if I edit in the console itself but does not work when I use my flutter app that uses the same database. Why?

Answer (score 2):

It does not work for Firestore, only Realtime Database.  There are currently no similar tools for Firestore.  Feel free to file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: But if so why the operation number increased from 0 to 1 when I edited a document in the console?

Comment: I don't know.  The documentation for the profiler will have more information.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile